# Django DIRS issue

Tags: django

I am learning Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial07/). It says , that i have to fill `DIRS` in `INSTALLED_APP`:
`'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`
That `templates` located in `project/templates` as they say. And now i somehow getting an error:
`...File "D:\KoronaTime\DjangoPython\FirstProject\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 58, in <module>`
`'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/ 'templates'],`
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates']
```